# Whitelabel error page in spring boot (type=Bad Request, status=400)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, error-handling

I am running Spring Boot application on the local machine on the port 8080. The application is starting successfully and I can test it through Postman. But when I try to access it from the browser, it gives me a whitelabel error page.

My request mapping in the controller is:

```java
 @RequestMapping(value = "/billing-file-generation",
        produces = {"application/json"},
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Also, I tried handling it with `Errorhandlercontroller` and couldn't fix the issue or get any idea about the issue, instead I could just customize the error message instead of whitelabel error page.

Any idea why this is happening? I have attched the error in the below image.

[Whitelabel error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YK4O.png)

Comment: You are calling `billing-file`, but your mapping is `billing-file-generation`. Enter the right URL into you browser.

Comment: It still has the same error with the right mapping.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
http://localhost:8080/usb/v1/billing-file-generation
```

instead of this,

```
 http://localhost:8080/usb/v1/billing-file
```

Comment: The same error.

Comment: Could u share more code?